# Gets freeze when call task without await

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm writing code with async/await for some requirement that I have to write some method like this

```
public bool Foo()
{ // not async
    return Foo_Async().Result;// get freeze
}

public Task<bool> Foo_Async()
{
    bool foo1Result = await Task.Run(()=>Foo1());
}
```

When execute, app gets freeze.

Comment: Yes ofcourse your app freezes. The call yo `.Result` is blocking. Its waiting for the task to finish.

Comment: Where do you need the result of Foo()?

Comment: hi @ckruczek I just want to run Foo_Async synchronously and return result after finished with await Task inside.

Comment: Well I am sorry to say that but thats not how the async part of c# was designed for. You better go and read a tutorial about it again and again and again and....well you know the rest.

Comment: This looks like the [`async` deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).